# mssql echo certain results

Tags: php, sql-server, echo

This is my first post here on stackoverflow but i used the site many many times so first of all i wanna thank you guys for all the great answers that you shared with the world. 
I used google and the search function before i post here but i couldnt find an answer that solved my problem.

The goal is to create a google stacked graph, but they demand a very specific array format. 
In most cases i managed to create a graph but for this one i cant get the output of the mssql query right.

The result i got through my query is the following

```
Name       Case       Count
Company A  Incident   6
Company A  Request    28
Company A  Problem    2
Company B  Incident   1
Company B  Problem    15
Company C  Incident   60
Company C  Problem    45
Company C  Request    30
Company C  Change     24
```

I achieved this result by the following simple SQL query

```
SELECT top 20
        CRM_MSCRM.dbo.FilteredAccount.name,
        CRM_MSCRM.dbo.FilteredIncident.casetypecodename, 

        count(casetypecodename) as count


        FROM 
             CRM_MSCRM.dbo.FilteredIncident
        JOIN CRM_MSCRM.dbo.FilteredAccount on CRM_MSCRM.dbo.FilteredIncident.bb_accounttocaseid = CRM_MSCRM.dbo.FilteredAccount.accountid

        GROUP BY 
             casetypecodename, name
```

If i echo this with PHP in an associated PHP list i get the following:

```
Company A 6
Company A 28
Company A 2
Company B 1
Company B 15
```

etc...

But what i need is the following:

```
Company A 6, 28, 2
Company B 2, 1
```

How can i echo my query (or a modified query to achieve the format that i need for my charts.

```
    ['Name', 'incident', 'change'],
    ['Company A', 10, 24, ],
    ['Company B', 16, 22, ],
    ['Company C', 28, 19, ]
```

This my PHP code, just a test page to get my result. Inserting this into a chart isnt the problem, the problem is the format that the chart demands.

```
$sql="
            // query goes here 

                ";
 $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
 if( $stmt === false) {die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );}
     while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) )
                    {                   
                        echo $row [name];
                        echo $row [tellen]; // but this doesnt work
                    }   

        ?>
```

How do i need to echo the results to achive my goal?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your PHP script ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: You only need a two-dimension array, don't you?

Comment: @ Alvaro Gonzalez: Yes i need a wo-dimension array

Comment: Then the syntax is `$foo['level1']['level2'] = 'Value'`.

Comment: Oke thank you for your answer.
What do you mean with level1 and level2? Ar these rows in my query or do i have to replace them with name and tellen (which means count in my language). Also what is value, what value do you mean? Sorry for my maybe dumb question(s) but i dont fully understand your answer. 

And $foo will result in an 2d array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a little note about your current code:

```
echo $row [name];
```

You apparently haven't configured your PHP development box to display all errors messages so you're coding blindly. I suggest you look into that until you can see the two notices you should be getting:

```
    Notice: Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name'
    Notice: Undefined index: name
```

I also suggest you review the basics of the PHP syntax, which is in fact not very different from other languages inspired by the C syntax. Learn about [string literals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) (and hoy they differ from [constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)) and of course [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

---

While you can certainly rewrite your SQL query to return the exact data format you need I don't think it's worth the effort when (if I understood the specs correctly) a simple PHP array will do the trick.

I have the impression the only problem is that you aren't familiar with the concept of arrays in programming languages. This is not the place for a full lecture but an array is a list of values where order matters and those values can be any PHP variable—including other arrays. This last bit is the key to convert this:

```
Company A 6
Company A 28
Company A 2
Company B 1
Company B 15
```

... into this:

```
Company A 6, 28, 2
Company B 2, 1
```

When you read the result set in the `sqlsrv_fetch_array()` loop you can just store the values in the 2-dimensional array. You can see the syntax in action in the [Recursive and multi-dimensional arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) example of the PHP manual but, in your case, it'd be:

```
$values = [];
while ( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $values[$row['name']][] = $row['casetypecodename'];
}
```

You can inspect the resulting array with e.g. [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump). When you're done, you can loop the external array with [foreach()](http://php.net/foreach) and merge each internal array into a comma-separated string with [implode()](http://php.net/implode).

Comment: Thank you for your advice, possible solution and feedback.
Unfortunately this code still doesnt what i  need. Now it only shows the first aantal number from a company like this:

    Company A 6
    Company B 1

It doesnt show the other numbers and i will try to solve this problem on my own. 
 
You said I code blindly, that isnt true, i do have the error messages from PHP enabled and yes there was a error in 'name'
I am no programmer but its part of my internship to build this intranetpage. This is the only "hard" SQL query i need, and I 
possess basic programming and SQL skils.

Comment: My bad, I had a missing pair of square brackets.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick respond. The solution works!